# Reading passwords without showing on screen in Bash Scripts

Tags: bash, password

How can one read passwords in bash scripts in such a way that tools do not show it on a terminal?

(Changing font to black-on-black is easily worked around by copy & paste, so it's not solution.)

Comment: For anyone reading this: do NOT read in passwords with echo on and black-on-black. The password is still transmitted, and if the terminal doesn't know the terminal directives you've used, characters will echo visibly. Turn echo off. Use `termios`, `stty`, `read -s`, anything that does it.

Comment: That's why I've wrote, that it is not a solution ;).

Comment: Indeed! Sometimes people skim questions and come to misguided conclusions. :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From `help read`:

> ```
> -s        do not echo input coming from a terminal
> ```

For example, to prompt the user and read an arbitrary password into the variable `passwd`,

```bsh
IFS= read -s -p 'Password please: ' passwd
```

Comment: Great. It's not written in my `man read`, I haven't check in `help read`. Good to know.

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: You are viewing the wrong manual. you have to read the manual of bash i.e `man bash` and there you can find -s option `Silent mode.  If input is  coming  from  a  terminal, characters are not echoed.`

Answer (score 11):

I always used `stty -echo` to turn echoing off, then read and afterwards do `stty echo` (read more by viewing man of `stty` - i.e. `man stty`). This is more useful from a programmers perspective as you can turn echoing off and then read a password from a programming language such as Java, C(++), Python, etc. with their standard stdin "readers."

In bash, the usage could look like this:

```
echo -n "USERNAME: "; IFS= read -r uname
echo -n "PASSWORD: "; stty -echo; IFS= read -r passwd; stty echo; echo
program "$uname" "$passwd"
unset -v passwd    # get rid of passwd
```

Python, for example, would look like:

```
from sys import stdout
from os import system as term

uname = raw_input("USERNAME: ") # read input from stdin until [Enter] in 2
stdout.write("PASSWORD: ")
term("stty -echo") # turn echo off
try:
    passwd = raw_input()
except KeyboardInterrupt: # ctrl+c pressed
    raise SystemExit("Password attempt interrupted")
except EOFError: # ctrl+d pressed
    raise SystemExit("Password attempt interrupted")
finally:
    term("stty echo") # turn echo on again

print "username:", uname
print "password:", "*" * len(passwd)
```

I had to do this a lot of times in Python, so I know it pretty well from that perspective. This isn't very hard to translate to other languages, though.

Comment: I'm finding that `stty -echo; sleep 3; stty echo` makes any characters entered show up _after_ the last command has completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with adding an external dependency, you may use a password box provided by tools such as dialog or whiptail.

[image: Whiptail]

Answer (score -2):

Your question reads kind of different "in a way like tools???" so I don't exactly know if this will work for you:

```
system1 $ passwd=abc123
system1 $ printf "%s\n" "${passwd//?/*}"
******
```