# Generate HMAC in Bash without revealing the secret

Tags: security, openssl, hashsum

I'd like to compute a HMAC-SHA512 digest in my bash script. So far I've found only this repeated many times over many different sites.

```
echo -n message | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac secret -binary >message.mac
```

Apparently no one posting this realizes this is not the proper way to pass a secret string to a program as the secret will be visible in the process list for every other process running on the system. Is there any other way (perhaps with other tool) to easily make an HMAC in the shell with better interface for passing secrets?

**UPDATE**

I use the following tool (`~/bin/hmac`) now. It takes the key from the `MACKEY` environment variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import hmac, sys, os

key    = os.environ['MACKEY'].encode('utf-8')
algo   = os.getenv('MACALGO', 'sha512')
digest = hmac.new(key, digestmod = algo)

while True:
    buf = sys.stdin.buffer.read(512)
    if not buf:
        break
    digest.update(buf)

print(digest.hexdigest())
```

Usage:

```
echo -n message | MACKEY=foobar hmac
```

Comment: Where is the secret now? (Just before the openssl call)

Comment: `-passin` would support envvars or files, but I can't see anything like that for a MAC key... And no, `-passin` itself doesn't work.

Comment: if you want to just hide the process from other users on the machine, you can remount `/proc` with `hidepid=2`: `mount -o remount,rw,hidepid=2 /proc` - don't forget to update fstab if you want /proc persistently mounted like that: `proc    /proc    proc    defaults,hidepid=2     0     0`. NB: this will obviously not be useful in your situation if you're trying to hide the secret entirely from ps/top outputs for all users.

Comment: @JeffSchaller In an environment variable where it got from file via `cat keys | { read api_key; read api_secret }`.

Comment: Check out [Hide arguments to program...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403870/119298).

Comment: run it on a single-user computer

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20282/78324

Comment: [Read here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78760/265604) *that should never be used as you can list environment, in many ps implementations by ps -e, in the /proc/<PID>/environ file on Linux etc.*

Answer (score 2):

Re-directions are not part of the argument list.

This are considered safe from ps snooping:

```
cmd </file/key
cmd <<<"key"
```

Un-named pipes are also possible inside an script

```
echo "secret" | cmd
```

[Example of secure password passing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232083/265604)

So, this script is regarded as secure:

```
#!/bin/bash

read secretkey </dev/stdin

var="<?= hash_hmac(\"sha512\", \"$1\", \"$secretkey\"); ?>"

php7.1 <<<"$var"
```

The `</dev/stdin` could be replaced with a `</dir/keyfile` if the key could be stored in a file.

For the `stdin` version, use it as this:

```
./script "Message" <<<"secretkey"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have asked the same question on [OpenSSL mailing list](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2022-August/015335.html)

If you are on Fedora 37 or RHEL 8, the `libkcapi-hmaccalc` package provides `sha1hmac`, `sha512hmac`, etc.

so you can replace:

```
$ echo -n toto | openssl dgst -hmac tata -sha1
SHA1(stdin)= 6c497bab7bcc37d768364b570445ee10a4fb17d6
```

with

```
$ echo -n toto | sha1hmac -k <(echo -n tata) 
6c497bab7bcc37d768364b570445ee10a4fb17d6
```

see [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sha1hmac)

This prevents the secret key to leak in the process list (you still need to check that the key is not written in the Bash history, but this was not the scope of your question).