# svn authentication on unsafe machine

Tags: bash, environment-variables, password, authentication, subversion

i need to access some repository on an unsafe server. I dont want to store my password anywhere else than current session. What I came up with so far is combination of

```
histcontrol ignorespace
```

then exporting my password

```
$> export SOMEVARIABLE=MySecretPassword
```

and then access the repo like so:

```
$>svn co --password=$SOMEVARIABLE <repository>
```

is there any better way? I'd like to avoid the `--password=$SOMEVARIABLE` if possible

Comment: Unsafe server is unsafe. Change password for this very unsafe session or better copy needed files and host them elsewhere so there is no interaction with original server. You might consider also using oauth tokens or other one-time-password / 2fa

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232063/117549

Comment: A possible workaround could be mounting remote folder to your local safe workstation where you can use local svn client. Installed `fuse` and `sshfs` packages is however a prerequisite for that. If that's the case and you see it an option I can make it an answer.